# From char* array to two dimentional array and back algorithm goes wrong

Tags: objective-c, c, algorithm

I think my algorithm has flawed logic somewhere. Calling the two functions should return the same image however it doesn't! Can anyone see where my logic goes wrong?

These functions are used on PNG-images, I have found that they store colors as follows: ALPHA, RED, GREEN, BLUE. Repeatingly for the whole image. "pixels" is just a long array of those values (like a list).

My intent is to do a lowpass filter on the image, which is a lot easier logic if you instead use a two dimentional array / matrix of the image.

```
// loading pixels
UIImage *image      = imageView.image;
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
NSData *data        = (NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
char *pixels        = (char *)[data bytes];

// editing image
char** matrix = [self mallocMatrix:pixels withWidth:CGImageGetWidth(imageRef) andHeight:CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)];
char* newPixels = [self mallocMatrixToList:matrix withWidth:CGImageGetWidth(imageRef) andHeight:CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)];
pixels = newPixels;
```

and the functions looks like this:

```
- (char**)mallocMatrix:(char*)pixels withWidth:(int)width andHeight:(int)height {
    char** matrix = malloc(sizeof(char*)*height);
    int c = 0;
    for (int h=0; h < height; h++) {
        matrix[h] = malloc(sizeof(char)*width*4);
        for (int w=0; w < (width*4); w++) {
            matrix[h][w] = pixels[c];
            c++;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

- (char*)mallocMatrixToList:(char**)matrix withWidth:(int)width andHeight:(int)height {
    char* pixels = malloc(sizeof(char)*height*width*4);
    int c = 0;
    for (int h=0; h < height; h++) {
        for (int w=0; w < (width*4); w++) {
            pixels[c] = matrix[h][w];
            c++;
        }
    }
    return pixels;
}
```

**Edit:** Fixed the malloc as posters pointed out. Simplified the algorithm a bit.

Comment: `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(char)` make sure when you malloc `matrix[h]` you malloc `sizeof(char) * width * 4` and the same for your `mallocLowPassFilter`

Comment: Is there padding in PNG files for when the width of your image is not a multiple of 4?

Comment: Could you show us how the output differs from the input?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean Shahbaz but all PNG-files I've tested has had 4 channels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested your code but it appears you are allocating the incorrect size for your matrix and low pass filter as well as not moving to the next pixel correctly.

```
- (char**) mallocMatrix:(char*)pixels withWidth:(int)width andHeight:(int)height {
    //When using Objective-C do not cast malloc (only do so with Objective-C++)
    char** matrix = malloc(sizeof(char*)*height);
    for (int h=0; h < height; h++) {
        //Each row needs to malloc the sizeof(char) not char *
        matrix[h] = malloc(sizeof(char)*width*4);
        for (int w=0; w < width; w++) {
            // Varje pixel har ARGB
            for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
                matrix[h][w+i] = pixels[h*w+i];
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

- (char*) mallocLowPassFilter:(char**)matrix withWidth:(int)width andHeight:(int)height 
{
    //Same as before only malloc sizeof(char)
    char* pixels = malloc(sizeof(char)*height*width*4);
    for (int h=0; h < height; h++) {
        for (int w=0; w < width; w++) {
            // Varje pixel har ARGB
            for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
                // TODO: Lowpass here
                pixels[h*w+i] = matrix[h][w+i];
            }
        }
    }
    return pixels;
}
```

Note: This code, as you know, is limited to ARGB images. If you would like to support more image formats there are additional functions available to get more information about your image such as [CGImageGetColorSpace](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageGetColorSpace) to find the pixel format (ARGB, RGBA, RGB, etc...), and [CGImageGetBytesPerRow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageGetBytesPerRow) to get the number of bytes per row (you wouldn't have to multiply width by channels per pixel).

Comment: Hey you where right about the malloc but the algorithm works correctly. The image is returned the same now, if you edit your answer accordingly I will mark it as correct! Cheers mate!

Comment: Hey I just discovered the algorithm wasn't actually working haha.. been doing this for hours so :p Now it is though so I think you where right about the indexes.. I'll fix my orgiginal post so the algorithm is correct at least

Comment: or actually i cant be bothered :P

Comment: Would you like for me to roll back to my `width * 4` and my `w+=4` ?

Comment: I've updated my original post to how it looks now, I can't figure out why it doesn't produce the same picture!